# How to edit default jWYSIWYG tag CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, default, jwysiwyg

Here's a nice, boring list:

1. jWYSIWYG generates HTML tags
2. Where does it get these default values from
3. Can they be edited

**UPDATE**

With no means to edit the default values (short of creating a new custom button from scratch), the only way I found to circumvent default jWYSIWYG behaviors was in the stylesheet. This means that while the tag attributes remain, the styles can be overridden. Annoying but it works.

Hopefully this helps somebody-jWYSIWYG is a handy little plugin.

Comment: Didn't mean for it to sound like a "rant"...just a Sunday morning conundrum. I thought the post was specific enough: jWYSIWYG must be getting its default CSS values from somewhere...where are they located and can those defaults be edited?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify and create new controls with your configuration options, I'd imagine overriding existing controls would be as simple as using the same key (quote in this case).

https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg#available-configuration-options

> Additionally, custom controls may be specified by adding new keys with
>   the same signature as a control object. For example, if we wish to
>   create a quote control which creates  tags, we could do
>   specify this key:

```
quote: { visible: true, tags: ['blockquote'], css: { class: 'quote', className: 'quote' }
```

If you want to get into the nuts and bolts of it you can always edit the source controls file https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/blob/master/src/controls/default.js - you'll need to follow the build process to rebuild afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @Dontfeedthecode I have custom fields already set up but didn't see the need in this case since an indent/blockquote function is already there. I've scoured the js file and can't seem to locate the settings it's using.